# Selecting First instance of subject in long and wide file in R

Tags: r, indexing, split

I have a large data set that is long and wide like this:

```
 StudentID <- factor(c(1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 5, 5))
 Grade <- factor(c(10, 10, 11, 11, 11, 10, 10, 10, 12, 9, 9))
 data <- data.frame(StudentID, Grade)
```

For each student ID there are potentially many instances of their grade level (which are always the same).

What is the most efficient way to pare this data set down so each student only has their grade level listed once?

So far, I've tried using the split function to create a list of all of the grades listed for each student and then sapply to only select the first element in the list:

```
 index.byID <- split(data$Grade, data$StudentID)
 sapply(index.byID, "[[", 1)
```

Because my data is so large (300K+ rows) it takes more than 25 minutes to do the indexing.

Any help you can provide would be great!

.        .

Comment: @akrun Thank you! I think the `unique()` function will work well!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try `unique`

```
unique(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

@akrun's answer is as simple as it gets for the purpose of answering the question.  But if you want to retain the value of other columns of the first record, I find using ddply from the plyr package a clean and efficient alternative.  Here is the code for this approach.

```
library(plyr)

StudentID <- factor(c(1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 5, 5))
Grade     <- factor(c(10, 10, 11, 11, 11, 10, 10, 10, 12, 9, 9))
data      <- data.frame(StudentID, Grade, 
                        ExtraColumn=1:length(StudentID))
ddply(data, .(StudentID, Grade), function(x) head(x, 1))
```